# ST_Transform Displaced Locations

Tags: postgis-2.0, coordinate-system, srid

Ive updated my spatial_ref_sys table in postgres with spatial reference statement from http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102737/.

I can perform the tranformation from srid 4326 to srid 102737 and receive no errors...

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, ...

SELECT id, name, ST_Transform(subs.geom, 102737) as geom
INTO subs4201
```

However the results when viewed on a map are displaced.

I can test this by using arcgis to reproject the data and the results overlay the wgs84 original locations....

[image]

How can I correct for this?

Edit: The displacement is approx. 1/2 mi.

Edit2: Adding ArcMap image as requested by @mkennedy

[image]

Comment: A half a mile is a lot. Maybe int'l feet versus US survey feet? Could the "102737" data have the wrong coordinate reference system attached? That is, 102737 use US survey feet, but maybe it's really using int'l feet?

Comment: Instead of "102737" can you try reprojecting to "2275?"

Comment: @mkennedy I can confirm US Feet...                                                         +proj=lcc +lat_1=36.18333333333333 +lat_2=34.65 +lat_0=34 +lon_0=-101.5 +x_0=200000.0001016002 +y_0=999999.9998983998 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs

Comment: I get the same shifted coordinates with 2275. I also tested with 3001 (NM East) and everytime same shifted coordinates? @Mintx

Comment: Oops, I should have checked the code first. I mixed this Q up with the North Carolina one. I don't see anything obvious in the definition. Is there anyway you can post a test point results? The original coordinates in lat/lon, plus the results from ST_Transform and ArcGIS?

Comment: Thank you for the picture. What I really wanted was some original lat/lon values from subs.geom, the result after ST_Transform from subs4201, and hopefully the projected result from ArcMap. I've guestimated values from the image. So far I'm stumped. I would suggest importing subs using 32138 (TX N meters) and see how that lines up. If it does, then we know something's going on in the US ft definition in PostGIS. (assuming that the ArcGIS values are in the rigth location.